# Problems using Ajax calls in reloaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am a novice writing a website using jquery and jquery mobile.  This loads a set of questions in the form of a JSON file, using jquery ajax, and then users work through questions. On first opening, the page successfully opens 2 JSON files using code that looks like this:

function loadJSON (keytoload) {

```
$.ajax({
    url: keytoload,
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (keyloaded)   {
                                     dataset=keyloaded;
                                     },
    error: function (request,error) {
                                    alert('Error has occurred please try again!');
                                    }
});        
}
```

I find that async has to be set to false for this to work.  If async is true, the page is displayed without the data from the JSON file.

After the user works through a series of steps, a new JSON file is loaded to replace the first and this usually works fine.  However, reloading the page is erratic.  It works fine in Firefox/Chrome on Windows, but throws an error if a page refresh is done when loading on Android Chrome.  So I assume there is a problem in my code somewhere.

Is there a better way I could do this?

Comment: From where are you calling this fn loadJSON ?  where is "dataset" defined?

Comment: You need to do the rendering in the `success`-handler, not just `dataset=keyloaded;` then you can remove the `async: false`

Comment: What is the error? Is anything printed in the console?

Comment: Ideally, you should keep async as true and update the pertinent sections of your page once the ajax call is successful (with a success callback).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is cause by the fact that you don't use ajax correctly. You don't know how long is going to take until the result comes back from the server.

A correct architecture here will be:

1. display an loading div before starting ajax.
2. On success add the questions in the page.
3. On next display the loading again.
4. On success render the new content.

Just setting an variable on success is wrong; on success you render the content based on the values from backend. Also using an ajax in a synchronous way is not recommended, since it can block the script.

Comment: Thanks!  That was my mistake.  Success was not calling the function which redrew the page.  Now works right with async: true and behaves in a sensible way.  Thanks for all the contributions